# Copy a request and send it to another server with httpmodule

Tags: c#, testing, deployment

I'm looking into a deployment scenario where we have a production environment (c# .net) and a "duplicate", refactored environment (the one to be deployed, and should work exactly as the production)

I'd like the users of the production environment to work as if nothing has changed, but would like their requests to be copied and sent to the refactored environment, either async or recorded and playbacked at a later time. The response to the user should be from the production.

So I've looked into creating a httpmodule intercepting the reqest in the production and somehow send the same reqest to the refactored env. Is it possible and have anyone done it before?

Any pointers would help.

cheers
/Ryan

Comment: Hi, will all requests be sent this way? Sounds a little like you need something sitting in front of your server like a proxy or a load balancer.

Comment: You can use ARR (Application Request Routing) and forwarding to get this working alot easier than writing your own proxy. Your own proxy will be quite slow I'd imagine comparatively.